# OSMDroid ItemizedOverlayWithBubble Map Balloons with a list

Tags: android, dictionary, osmdroid

I am using OSM droid and its Bonus Pack to create balloon popups when points in interest (POI) icons are clicked on the map. I am able to get an **ItemizedOverlayWithBubble** working very well. However, in some cases the POIs icons are very close making it hard for used to freely tap which one they want. A solution I thought was to amalgamate the POIs into one icon with a number on top. I have this working well also.

So what I would like to do is have an **ItemizedOverlayWithBubble**  which displays a small scrollable and selectable, list. Where clicking the item in the list takes the user to an additional screen  to elaborate on the POI.

From clues found in [this tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_2) I assumed the code below would work, but this fails to work, displaying only the last items in the **titles** and **descriptions** vectors only.

Any advice on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated.

```
       //================================================================================================================
      /**
       * Adds a map information bubble with a selectable list if items.
       * 
       * @param location The location of the info bubble on the map,
       * @param titles The titles to go in the info bubble.
       * @param descriptions The descriptions to go in the info bubble.
       * @param mapMarkerType The map marker type.
       */
      //================================================================================================================
      public void addMapInfoList(GeoPoint location, Vector<String> titles, Vector <String> descriptions, int mapMarkerType)
      {
           new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(this.ctx);
           Drawable localDrawable = getMapMarker( 8);

           ArrayList<ExtendedOverlayItem> localArrayList = new ArrayList<ExtendedOverlayItem>();//items list

           int i = 0;
           for (String title: titles)
           {

            String description = descriptions.get(i);
            ExtendedOverlayItem localExtendedOverlayItem = new ExtendedOverlayItem(title, description, location, this.ctx);
            localExtendedOverlayItem.setImage(this.ctx.getResources().getDrawable(2130837507));
            localExtendedOverlayItem.setMarkerHotspot(OverlayItem.HotspotPlace.CENTER);
            localExtendedOverlayItem.setMarker(localDrawable);
            localArrayList.add(localExtendedOverlayItem); 
            i++;
           }

           ItemizedOverlayWithBubble<ExtendedOverlayItem> localItemizedOverlayWithBubble = new ItemizedOverlayWithBubble<ExtendedOverlayItem>(this.ctx, localArrayList, this.map);

          // ItemizedOverlayWithBubble<ExtendedOverlayItem> poiMarkers =   new ItemizedOverlayWithBubble<ExtendedOverlayItem>(this, poiItems, map);

           this.map.getOverlays().add(localItemizedOverlayWithBubble);
      }//================================================================================================================
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem Andrew. Did you solve it?

Comment: No, I never found a way and did somthing else instead. Interestingly Google Maps API V2 as an Info window feature which allows this.